# Ordering Function

Tags: php

How I can make PHP create a file for each order named whatever the person enters there name into the field

```
<?php

Name:           php echo $_POST["Firstname"]; 
            php echo $_POST["Lastname"];   <br /> <br />
Dorm Name:      php echo $_POST["DormName"];   <br />

Room Number:    php echo $_POST["RoomNumber"];   <br />

Pizza Type      php echo $_POST["PizzaType"];   <br />

?>
```

This is what i have so far but I need a function that will make a file for each submission and name it the persons name.

Comment: you got all that inside the php tag?

Comment: Did you want to create a file for `Firstname`, `DormName`, `RoomNumber` and `PizzaType`?

Comment: yes but i want to name the file after what ever the person enters as their first and lsat name

Comment: So you want the filename to be `firstName_lastName.txt`, and the contents to be the information for `DormName`, `RoomNumber` and `PizzaType`?

Comment: correct but include the first and last name tool. btw thanks justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your PHP should look something like this...

```
<?php
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
    $firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
    $lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
    $dormName = $_POST["dormName"];
    $roomNumber = $_POST["roomNumber"];
    $pizzaType = $_POST["pizzaName"];

    $fp = fopen($firstName . "_" . $lastName . ".txt", "a"); // the 'a' will append to the end of the file.
    fwrite($fp, "\n\n");
    fwrite($fp, "First Name: $firstName\n");
    fwrite($fp, "Last Name: $lastName\n");
    fwrite($fp, "Dorm Name: $dormName\n");
    fwrite($fp, "Room Number: $roomNumber\n");
    fwrite($fp, "Pizza Type: $pizzaType\n");
    fclose($fp);
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" id="" action="">
            <input type="text" name="firstName" value="" />
            <input type="text" name="lastName" value="" />
            <input type="text" name="dormName" value="" />
            <input type="text" name="roomNumber" value="" />
            <input type="text" name="pizzaName" value="" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Note:** If another person with the same name orders again, it will all just append to the bottom of the same file.

Cheers

Comment: Though, to be honest, it would be better to store this information in a database.

Comment: Just a thought Justin. If the 'w' flag is used with fopen, won't it overwrite any contents if the file name is the same? Will the 'a' flag be safer?

Comment: hey justin when i submitted it created the file but it was called _.txt, also when i opened the file it didnt enter any of my data

Comment: @Phil the name of your input attribute needs to be the same as the name of the $_POST array element.

Comment: it still creates one file named _.txt and doesnt display any data in the text file

Comment: @PhilPilon `<input name="firstName" ..`?

Comment: @deizel are you asking if i put the input name exactly like that?

Comment: I just tested my code, works fine. I will edit my post with EXACTLY what I have...

Answer (score 0):

Try and have a read about fopen and fwrite.

Here's an example from the php codex:

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, '1');
fwrite($fp, '23');
fclose($fp);
// the content of 'data.txt' is now 123 and not 23!
```

So where that calls the file data.txt, you could call it a name based on $_POST['Firstname'] etc...

Comment: also i need it to not write it to the file it needs to make a seperate file for each order